# Help! enclosed porch/sunroom foundation

Tags: repair, concrete, foundation, porch

We just purchased a home and now that the snow level is not 4 feet high ( we live in central NY ) we see that the concrete patio/foundation has horizontal cracks, and crumbling along the side, corner and front wall of the sunroom that is visible. The other 2 walls are attached to the house. The back wall leading into the house is the original home exterior, the other side of the porch is also an exterior wall of the house. On this side of the front wall we can actually put our hand into the porch, the concrete floor and sunroom wall are not together anymore.  I can not find any information online of others having this issue, is this something a contractor could fix or does it need to be torn down.

Comment: Please add photos.

Comment: It is not clear from your description, what the situation is.

Comment: A picture would be great, your description works great in your mind, but we have not seen the place. It seems that you are saying that a patio type slab was poured, without any support or structure under it. So it is just a slab on dirt. The sunroom was made by building 2 walls, which connect and form one corner of the sunroom, and then connecting them to 2 walls of the 'true' house. Some of the slab has sunk several inches into the dirt, and the forms a 'bridge' over the slab. The wall is in place, but the slab dropped. You could set a marble on the floor and would roll outside. Am I close?

Comment: Some guy.. you can see into my mind.  I wasn't able to upload the picture.  We were able to have a local mason and general contractor come and see the issue. Both stated that the sunroom is still structurally sound. The concrete patio that the sunroom was built on has sunken a bit causing the gap or space. The mason stated that the concrete (horizontal crack and crumbling in corner) can be repaired with wire lath and mortar. The contractor said the corner needed to be dug out and replaced. Very different ways of repairing it. thank you both for responding